# Stop pyspark returning both 'on' columns after joining

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Dataframes in PySpark and would like to perform an outer join on them.  I need to be able to join them on column names that are different in each table and may change (so need to be a variable, not hardcoded).  However, when I do this at the moment, PySpark returns a dataframe including both columns that are being joined on, with some values populated with nulls.

An example of the code I'm currently using is:

```
>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame([[1,'apple'],[2,'orange']], ['id_fruit','fruit'])
>>> df2 = spark.createDataFrame([[2,100],[3,30]], ['fruit_id','numberInStock'])

>>> df1.show()
+--------+------+
|id_fruit| fruit|
+--------+------+
|       1| apple|
|       2|orange|
+--------+------+


>>> df2.show()
+--------+-------------+
|fruit_id|numberInStock|
+--------+-------------+
|       2|          100|
|       3|           30|
+--------+-------------+

>>> left_join_on = 'id_fruit'
>>> right_join_on = 'fruit_id'


>>> df1.join(df2, df1[left_join_on] == df2[right_join_on], how='outer').show()
+--------+------+--------+-------------+
|id_fruit| fruit|fruit_id|numberInStock|
+--------+------+--------+-------------+
|       1| apple|    null|         null|
|    null|  null|       3|           30|
|       2|orange|       2|          100|
+--------+------+--------+-------------+
```

As above, both columns that are being used to join on are being preserved.  For inner joins, this would be fine (I could just drop one of the columns for instance), but with the outer join I really need both of the ID values in the same column (e.g. in case I wanted to do a subsequent join).  Ideally the output I want would look something like this:

```
+--------+------+-------------+
|id_fruit| fruit|numberInStock|
+--------+------+-------------+
|       1| apple|         null|
|       3|  null|           30|
|       2|orange|          100|
+--------+------+-------------+
```

with only one ID column.  Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `coalesce` the two columns:

```
df1.join(df2, df1[left_join_on] == df2[right_join_on], how='outer') \
   .select('*', F.coalesce(F.col(left_join_on), F.col(right_join_on))) \
   .show()
```

If you want to keep that coalesced column only,

```
df1.join(df2, df1[left_join_on] == df2[right_join_on], how='outer') \
   .select('*', F.coalesce(F.col(left_join_on), F.col(right_join_on)).alias('coalesced')) \
   .drop(left_join_on, right_join_on) \
   .show()
```